# How to set read preference to secondaryPreferred for one query

Tags: mongoose

I'd like to execute a single aggregate query with the read preference secondaryPreferred.  Is this as simple as just calling read('secondaryPreferred') on that one query or will this cause a cascading change to the collection or socket for all operations that use the model or socket?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting read('secondaryPreferred') on a model's find operation will use the secondary for that read only.